# In xml-conduit, what is the "proper" way to pass a cursor to a function?

Tags: xml, haskell

From a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897737/how-to-parse-gpx-file-using-haskells-xml-conduit) I asked, I learned how to use `xml-conduit` to do some basic XML parsing of GPX files.

After some fidgeting, I now have a function that processes GPX files as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Text           as T
import Text.XML
import Text.XML.Cursor

data Trkpt = Trkpt {
  trkptTime :: Text,
  trkptLat  :: Text,
  trkptLon  :: Text
  } deriving (Show)

trkptsFromFile path =
  trkpts . fromDocument <$> Text.XML.readFile def path

trkpts cur =
  (cur $/ elm "trk" &/ elm "trkseg" &/ elm "trkpt") >>= extract
  where
    elm n = element $ Name n (Just "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1") Nothing
    extract cur = do
      let time = T.concat $ cur $/ elm "time" &// content
      let lat  = T.concat $ attribute "lat" cur
      let lon  = T.concat $ attribute "lon" cur
      return $ Trkpt time lat lon
```

In particular, I have the line:

```
  (cur $/ elm "trk" &/ elm "trkseg" &/ elm "trkpt") >>= extract
```

and I noticed I have to wrap the first part in parentheses in order to `>>=` it to my `extract` function. Is this the proper way to do this or is there some idiomatic way using the operators provided in the `xml-conduit` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `>=>` instead of `>>=` to avoid the parentheses:

```
(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> (a -> m c)

-- Specializing for m ~ [] and a ~ Cursor Node and b ~ Cursor Node
(>=>) :: Axis Node -> (Cursor Node -> [c]) -> Cursor Node -> [c]

cur $/ elm "trk" &/ elm "trkseg" &/ elm "trkpt" >=> extract
```

So `(>=>)` works like `(&/)`, but without retrieving the children of the current node first.

*Disclaimer: I haven't actually tried this*

Comment: Thanks, it worked. This cursor/axis terminology is confusing me still. Have to work on it.

Comment: @Ana A `Cursor` just refers to a single Node (and allows efficient navigating, like getting children/parent/siblings). An 'Axis' is just something which given a `Cursor` to a `Node`, returns a list of `Cursor`s (so `Cursor -> [Cursor]`). So an 'Axis' is just a kind of query: given a Node, it returns a list of Nodes that match the query.